# La Lista despegable de bootstrap no funciona

Tags: html, bootstrap, web, dropdownlist, frontend

quiero implementar una lista desplegable(dropdown) a al sitio web que estoy desarrollando, he estado ocupando un poco de Bootstrap y quise agarrar el dropdown de ahí pero por algún motivo que desconozco no funciona, si alguien puede ayudarme se los agradecería de antemano gracias.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    

<!-- Large button groups (default and split) -->
<div class="dropdown show">
    <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown link
    </a>
  
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Saludos. Prueba lo siguiente; Completa las url que tienes para **jquery.min.js** y **bootstrap.min.js**; solo tienes el inicio desde el **//** te hace falta el **https:** a menos que tu origen donde tienes esos JS este correcto conforme a la estructura de tu sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tienes los scripts de las librerias incorrectos, te falta el de popper que es el que bootstrap usa para los dropdowns, el jquery estas poniendo una version muy antigua y tienes 2 versiones de bootstrap distintas, pruebalo asi:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    

<!-- Large button groups (default and split) -->
<div class="dropdown show">
    <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown link
    </a>
  
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-VHvPCCyXqtD5DqJeNxl2dtTyhF78xXNXdkwX1CZeRusQfRKp+tA7hAShOK/B/fQ2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ni siquiera de rodillas soy digno de estar ante tu presencia, eres un dios, funciono a la perfección , siempre me dan  problemas las librerías, te lo agradezco muchísimo, un abrazo.

Comment: Jaja, gracias, pero si entras a la web de bootstrap esta al comienzo la explicacion, solo tienes q elegir la version q estas usando. Esta muy bien explicado. Saludos!